# image sizes - responsive

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a bootstrap layout with 2 portrait images in 1 column and 3 images in another landscape. At most sizes the columns equal the same height:

2 x portrait = 1008px
3 x landscape = 1008px

but now and then when resizing browser, a 1px / 2px margin will appear at the bottom of one of the columns (not always same column). I know this is to do with the images resizing slightly different but not sure why they're and how to fix it! For example at one size the portrait images are both 452px in height equalling 904px, where as the landscape one's are 302px equalling 906px.

Images are all set to 100% width, auto height and vertically aligned.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us some code, codepen/jsfiddle

Comment: try set the example up on one of the sites i mentioned, that code doesn't tell us much unfortunately. My gut feeling is it might be something to do with vertical alignment but can't be sure

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7qydjnk5/ here you go .. you can see if you resize the box, the image will go from being in line to not. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your images have classes of `"land"` and `"port"` but these classes aren't in your CSS example.

Have you tried adding the Bootstrap class `class="img-responsive"` which should make them behave the same?

It might also help adding a container to help group everything together, though I've not been able to recreate the issue you have explained at all using your fiddle in Internet Explorer. What browsers are you using/have you tested it with? If it's browser specific you can add a media query to target a specific browser (IE or Firefox for example).

Comment: The classes are unnecessary and make no difference. I shouldn't have added them in to avoid confusion. I have tested in all browsers and had the same issue. I've realised it is to do with how images resize and nothing to do with my code etc. I have fixed the issue with a small hack of hiding the extra gap. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted